# How do I tell meson setup about the location of a dependency?

Tags: cmake, pkg-config, meson-build, build-dependencies, mpv

I'm trying to build [celluloid](https://github.com/celluloid-player/celluloid/), which uses meson. I ran meson, but it failed to find an appropriate version of mpv:

```
Determining dependency 'mpv' with pkg-config executable '/usr/bin/pkg-config'
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --modversion mpv` -> 1

Found CMake: /usr/bin/cmake (3.13.4)

Determining dependency 'mpv' with CMake executable '/usr/bin/cmake'
Try CMake generator: auto
Called `/usr/bin/cmake --trace-expand -DNAME=mpv .` in /tmp/celluloid-0.20/build/meson-private/cmake_mpv -> 0
Dependency mpv found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)

src/meson.build:125:0: ERROR:  Dependency "mpv" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake
```

so I downloaded and built the latest [mpv](https://mpv.io/) release (0.33.0), built and installed it at `/opt/mpv`.

Now - how do I tell meson to take `mpv` from this new path?

Note: The relevant snippet of the meson files seems to be:

```
executable('celluloid', sources,
  dependencies: [
    libgtk,
    libgio,
    meson.get_compiler('c').find_library('m', required: false),
    dependency('mpv', version: '>= 1.107'),
    dependency('epoxy')
  ],
  link_with: extra_libs,
  include_directories: includes,
  c_args: cflags,
  install: true
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tell *meson* about your dependency by letting *pkgconfig* know about your dependency...

and that can be done by adding your dependency's path to the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable; it is delimited by colons, just like `PATH`, e.g. `/opt/foo:/opt/extra/baz`.

Remember that you may also need to add associated paths to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` after building and installing with a custom-built directory.